# Error with running LDA of flipmultivariates package on radiotelemetry data

Tags: r, dplyr, social-networking

I'm trying to run an LDA on a group of radio-tracked birds from a number of different flocks which I have done over a number of winter seasons. In this case the predictor values are the signal strengths from 4 radio-towers with the flocks as the class variables. I think this is an creative use of LDA on a big data project and might therefore may be relevant to others.

I'm using the flipmultivariates package and followed this site as best I could: https://www.displayr.com/linear-discriminant-analysis-in-r-an-introduction/, and set up my data accordingly. Here are the first few lines:

```
structure(list(mfgID = c("337", "337", "337", "337", "337", "337"
), `month(ts)` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `day(ts)` = 7:12, CP = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, -63.32, -60.181), Elnina = c(NA, -24.1004, -25.5027, 
-36.6236, -67.3128, NA), hans = c(-62.9033, -60.6047, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), Nanoswamp = c(-47.0282, -41.3482, -49.6897, -53.9879, 
NA, NA), flockID = c("EF", "EF", "EF", "EF", "EF", "EF")), class =     "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

I'm running the code:

```
lda1 <- LDA(flockID ~ Nanoswamp, hans , Elnina , CP,
    data    = FlocksforLDA2,
    missing = "Exclude cases with missing data",
    output  = "Scatterplot")
```

I keep getting this error message:

**Error in EstimationData(form, data, subset, weights, missing, seed = seed) : There are fewer observations (0) than there are variables (2)**

I've quite a number of NAs but I thought the missing line code above would address this. I'm using the flipmultivariates package because it greatly simplifies the LDA code and provides nice figures which is important.

If I've missed something silly I apologize, but any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: consider using `dput(head(your_df))` to output a reproducible data example.

Comment: Oh cool thanks, I just made the edit